# How to keep wizard open in background when I call up on an action button in odoo 12

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

In odoo 12,
How to keep a wizard open (in background) when I call up on an action button which opens an ir.actions.act_window ? The main wizard keeps getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is Odoo default behavior, if you are opening new `ir.actions.act_window` with `'target'` as `'new'`, what you can do is on the button action return the previous `ir.actions.act_window`.